# how to retrieve the encoding of a csv file in c#.net?

Tags: c#, encoding, csv, format

I need to get the encoding type of a csv file and how can i do this in c#.net..

My code to avoid Byte Order Mapping(BMO) added during UTF8 encoding is as follows:

```
     public static void SaveAsUTF8WithoutByteOrderMark(string fileName, Encoding encoding)
     {
        if (fileName == null)
             throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");

    if (encoding == null)
    {
        encoding = Encoding.Default;
    }

    File.WriteAllText(fileName, File.ReadAllText(fileName, encoding), new UTF8Encoding(false));
      }
```

But any one please tell me how i can find the encoding of a csv file in C#.net..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an example of a simple class that will detect the encoding [here](http://www.architectshack.com/TextFileEncodingDetector.ashx) (which doesn't just check for `BOM`).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [CharsetDetector/UTF-unknown](https://github.com/CharsetDetector/UTF-unknown) to find the encoding of a csv file. It's a Charset detector build in C# - .NET 5, .NET Core 2-3, .NET standard 1-2 & .NET 4+.

> Detect character set for files, streams and other bytes.

> This package is based on [Ude](https://github.com/errepi/ude) and since version 2 also on [uchardet](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/uchardet/uchardet), which are ports of the [Mozilla Universal Charset Detector](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/extensions/universalchardet/).

```
// Detect from File (NET standard 1.3+ or .NET 4+)
DetectionResult result = CharsetDetector.DetectFromFile("path/to/file.txt"); // or pass FileInfo

// Get the best Detection
DetectionDetail resultDetected = results.Detected;

// Get the alias of the found encoding
string encodingName = resultDetected.EncodingName;

// Get the System.Text.Encoding of the found encoding (can be null if not available)
Encoding encoding = resultDetected.Encoding;
```

Additional, here is a Python character encoding detector: [Chardet: The Universal Character Encoding Detector](https://github.com/chardet/chardet)